# What is the reasoning to choose the number of sockets?

Tags: cpu, processor-socket

I am looking at 2 servers.

One has got 12 sockets with 24 virtual processors.

Another server has got 24 sockets with 24 virtual processors.

What is the reasoning to choose the number of sockets?

Comment: Sockets or cores? I'm not convinced that you actually have a server with a dozen or two of single-core processors.

Comment: I can see the number of sockets in the task manager on the server. Where do I check for cores. Note: it is a virtualized machine.

Comment: Our storage admin tells me that that both machines have 2 NUMA nodes each.

Comment: Why don't you provide specific information about the processors in these mythical servers?  NUMA nodes don't tell us anything. [Edit] your question to improve the quality of this question.

Comment: 2 NUMA nodes, with the number of sockets and virtual processors as given in the question. What other info do you want.

Comment: Virtually all x86 CPUs were multi-core since 2006, probably even earlier in the server space. It's unlikely that you're actually dealing with a dozen sockets with a single-core CPU in each unless that stuff is _ancient_. Therefore your servers almost certainly don't actually have 12 sockets. In fact I'd guess they have just one or two, with 12-core CPUs in them, or maybe a 24-core CPU in a single socket. So please give us exact CPU model because we can't make sense from this data.

Comment: Since a 24 socket motherboard doesn't exist in reality, the physical hardware for these two configurations is probably identical.  So the real question here is what is the difference between these configurations in the virtual machine.